# SQL Reporting services for Microsoft SBS 2003 not working

Tags: iis-6, windows-sbs-2003, ssrs

I have a clean install of MS SBS 2003 Premium.  I installed MSSQL 2000 with SP4.  Now I am trying to install CRM 3.0 that requires SQL Reporting Services - but it says its not there.

When I go to Add/Remove programs "Microsoft SQL Server 2000 Reporting Services Standard Edition" is listed.

I read somewhere that if reporting services was installed / set up then there would be a site under IIS names "ReportingServices" (or something along those lines).  I do not have those - the only two I don't know are Microsoft SharePoint Administration and SharePoint Central Administration.

Questions: 1. how do I set up reporting services and get it running?  2. are ms sharpoint admin and sharepoint central sites under the IIS related to reporting services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check "table 5" in the [SQL Server™ 2000 Reporting Services Deployment Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966443.aspx) on TechNet